# How to find info field from jpcap

Tags: java, networking, wireshark, jpcap

I am using jpcap for packet sniffing. In wire shark we have fields named "No", "Time", "Source", "Destination", "protocol", "Length", "Info". I am able to extract all the fields using jpcap except for info fields. Can anyone tell me how to extract this field?

Answer (score 2):

> Can anyone tell me how to extract this field?

1. Download Wireshark.
2. Read the source to everything in the `dissectors` subdirectory of the `epan` directory and in the subdirectories of the `plugins` directory.
3. Reimplement all of that in your program.

Easy!

More seriously, the "Info" field is not something that's calculated in a simple fashion from the packet contents; it's produced by Wireshark's packet dissection code, of which there are several *million* lines.  It's not something you "extract"; it's something you write dissectors to *produce*, and duplicating that part of Wireshark would be a difficult job.